# Should I implement Display or ToString to render a type as a string?

Tags: string, rust

I have a type `Foo` that I want to be able to display to the end user as a string, is it more idiomatic to do this by implementing [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) or by implementing [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html)?

If `Display` is the way to go, how would I actually end up with a `String`? I suspect I need to make use of `write!`, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should not implement [`ToString`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) manually. The `ToString` trait is already implemented for all types which implement `fmt::Display`:

```
impl<T> ToString for T
where
    T: Display + ?Sized, 
{ /* ... */ }
```

If you implement `Display`, `to_string()` will be available on your type automatically.

[`fmt::Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) is intended to be implemented manually for those select few types which should be displayed to the user, while [`fmt::Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) is expected to be implemented for *all* types in such a way that represents their internals most nicely (for most types this means that they should have `#[derive(Debug)]` on them).

In order to obtain the string representation of `fmt::Debug` output you need to use `format!("{:?}", value)`, with `{:?}` being a placeholder for types which implement `fmt::Debug`.

[RFC 565](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0565-show-string-guidelines.md) defines guidelines for when to use `fmt::Debug` and `fmt::Display`.